Override NSwag model template
In my app I create a NSwag client that keeps adding this attribute value to my generated models/dto properties:
NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)

I tried everything to somehow remove it by configuration, but nothing works. Adjusting it manually in the generated client or by some post script is no option.
I have seen you can somehow override the template, but I didnt find the correct default template file in the "Template" folder of the repo. Am I missing something?
